# how to automatically start new song after old one ends

Tags: java, swing, audio, mp3

I am making an MP3 player but my problem is I cant automatically start a new song after the old one is finished. I have tried using isComplete()

Then I tried finding the length of the song and using thread.sleep() and I set it as the same length as my song so when the song is over a new one starts and it worked, the only problem is I cant click on any buttons and when i try to exit nothing happens, the song keeps playing and a new one will start but the window freezes

If you could help that would be great (The problem is around line 312)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.*;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.*;

import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
import javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.file.MpegAudioFileReader;


public class PPR extends JPanel{

private static long startTime;
private static long stopTime;
static int ms;

static int songnumber = 0;
static String song;
static Long duration;
//Above is the song number and the path
static File test = new File ("C:/Users/cmtc/Documents/WorkSpace/Mp3 Player/music/aa.mp3");

static File[] files = new File("music").listFiles();
static LinkedList songnames = new LinkedList();
//above is the array that gets all of the files and the linked list that gets all the names



 private final static int NOTSTARTED = 0;
 private final static int PLAYING = 1;
 private final static int PAUSED = 2;
 private final static int FINISHED = 3;
    //above tell the player what is happening


    private final Object playerLock = new Object();
    //not sure if i need above


    private static int playerStatus = NOTSTARTED;
    //above starts off by saying the player hasnt started yet


static JFrame f = new JFrame();
static JPanel p = new JPanel();
static String filename = "this string doesnt matter";


//above is the jpanel and jframe

 static FileInputStream input; 
 static MP3 player; 
 //above allows for file io and the mp3 player

    static Runnable Graphic = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         gui();
     }
 };

 // I had to make threads so that more than one button is visible

 public static void invokeLater(Runnable doRun){
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Graphic);
}

 //above is what allows multiple buttons to be visible




public PPR(){

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Graphic);
}

//above is similar to what is above this


public static void gui(){
    f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(1600,900);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(p);

    PlayPauseRewind();

}

//above is baseically what runs the three buttons

public static void PlayPauseRewind(){




    Object play = ppr(80,26,25,25,"pics/play.jpg");

    ((AbstractButton) play).addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            startTime = e.getWhen();
            if (playerStatus == PLAYING){
                pause();
                playerStatus = PAUSED;
            }else if (playerStatus == NOTSTARTED){
                 play();
                 playerStatus = PLAYING;
            }else if (playerStatus == PAUSED){
             resume();
             playerStatus = PLAYING;
        }


        }

    });



    //above is play ***************************************


    Object next = ppr(120,26,25,25,"pics/next.png");
    ((AbstractButton) next).addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (songnumber == files.length-1){
                System.out.println("No More songs");
            }else if (playerStatus == NOTSTARTED){
                play();
                playerStatus = PLAYING;
                pause();
                 playerStatus = PAUSED;
                 songnumber++;
                 play();
                    playerStatus = PLAYING;
                System.out.println(songnumber);
            }else if (playerStatus == PAUSED){
                songnumber++;
                play();
                pause();
                playerStatus = PAUSED;
                System.out.println(songnumber);
            }else{
            stop();
            songnumber++;
            System.out.println(songnumber);

            //above tells the next button what to do below is the try/catch


            try {
                input = new FileInputStream(allsongs(songnumber,song)); 
                player = new MP3(input);

                // start playing
                player.play();

                // after 5 secs, pause

            } catch (final Exception e1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e1);
            }
            playerStatus = PLAYING;
            }   
        }
    });



    Object back = ppr(40,26,25,25,"pics/back.png");
    ((AbstractButton) back).addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (songnumber == 0){
                System.out.println("No More songs");
            }else if (playerStatus == NOTSTARTED){
                play();
                playerStatus = PLAYING;
                pause();
                 playerStatus = PAUSED;
                 songnumber--;
                 play();
                    playerStatus = PLAYING;
                System.out.println(songnumber);
            }else if (playerStatus == PAUSED){
                songnumber--;
                play();
                pause();
                playerStatus = PAUSED;
                System.out.println(songnumber);
            }else{
            stop();
            songnumber--;
            System.out.println(songnumber);

            //above tells the back button what to do below is the try/catch

            try {
                input = new FileInputStream(allsongs(songnumber,song)); 
                player = new MP3(input);

                // start playing
                player.play();

                // after 5 secs, pause

            } catch (final Exception e1) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e1);
            }
            playerStatus = PLAYING;
            }   
        }
    });

}

public static Object ppr(int x, int y, int width, int height, String file){
    p.setLayout(null);      

    Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image player = tool.getImage(file);
            ImageIcon playbutton = new ImageIcon(player);

    JButton play = new JButton(playbutton);
        play.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

            return p.add(play);

            //above is a method that makes creating buttons very easy
}


public static void play(){
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(allsongs(songnumber,song)); 
        player = new MP3(input);

        player.play();

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    playerStatus = PLAYING;

    nextsong();


}

//above is the play method




public static void pause(){
    try {

        // start playing
        player.pause();

        // after 5 secs, pause

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    playerStatus = PAUSED;
}
//above is the pause method

public static void resume(){
    try {

        // start playing
        player.resume();

        // after 5 secs, pause

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static void length(){

    long size = files[songnumber].length();
    AudioFileFormat baseFileFormat;
    int ms = 0;
    try {
        baseFileFormat = new MpegAudioFileReader().getAudioFileFormat(files[songnumber]);
        Map properties = baseFileFormat.properties();
        duration = (Long) properties.get("duration");
        duration = duration/1000;
        ms = (int) (duration/10);
        System.out.println(ms);
        //System.out.println(size);
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//ABOVE AND BELOW IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO FIX IT;

public static void nextsong(){
    length(); 
    try {
        Thread.sleep(duration);
        stop();
        songnumber++;
        play();
        playerStatus=PLAYING;

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void stop(){
    try {

        player.stop();

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

//above is the resume method

public static void temp(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Action Listener is working");
}
//above is what I use to make sure the actionlistener is working I wont need it eventually

public static String allsongs(int songnumber,String song){
            for (int i = 0; i<files.length;i++){

            songnames.add("music/" + files[i].getName());   

            song = (String) songnames.get(songnumber);

        }
            return song;
    }

//above is the loop that goes through the folder and names everysong while         assigning it a song number


}
```

Comment: Please only post relevant code next time if you want an answer. If you post that much code, nobody will really read it.

Comment: What do you mean using the `isComplete()` method didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You are using some kind of MP3 player, which I can not track wher it comes from as I can not find the matching import statement:

```
 player = new MP3(input);

 player.play();
```

Most common thing to do is to add a listener to player (if that is supported in your MP3 class) like

```
player.addXXXListener(new XXXListener(){});
```

The XXXlistener would have a method that is being called when it has finished playing, in that method you can start your next song.

So it depends on what your MP3 class supports.

Comment: my problem is i cant call it, because the code doesnt tell me when the song is finished playing

Comment: The song should do a callback when it is finished playing. Where is the MP3.java that you are using coming from?

Comment: You are also using Player from javazoom. If you start using AdvancedPlayer (in your MP3.java? Just geussing here as you did not answer my question on that) from javazoom, you can set the PlaybackListener, which will give you callback when it is finished.